# How to increment a variable that initialize with value '0' for function that gets recalled for many times?

Tags: c#, function, counter, increment

This is my C# coding. I want to increment the variable counter every times I recall this function. Is there any way to make the counter variable increment by 1 every times I recall this function?

```
private void _CalculateValue()
{
     double b = 0.1;

     int counter = 0;

     a = a * b;

     counter++;    
}
```

Comment: Counter is being incremented in your code. Although, this seems to serve no purpose since the ***same*** counter variable will never be touched again after the function has finished executing.

Comment: can you add a static field to the class containing this method to increment?

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
class customClass
{

    int classLevelCounter = 0;

    private void _CalculateValue()
    {
        double b = 0.1;

        a = _a * b;

        classLevelCounter++;
    }

}
```

In your question `counter` is created in the method and destroyed (looses its value) as soon as method gets over since its scope is only method. Hence next time it will again initialize from 0.

In my answer the `classLevelCounter` retains its value even after method gets over as its scope is `Class`.

Here is a working example.

[image]

Comment: The variable would not be global. It's class-level.

Comment: I think all of these examples need to have the variable as static and/or be in a static class.  I guess we need to know if this is counter will be different for each object, but this type of method doesn't appear to be.

Comment: @Harrison: No that is not necessary. Look at the picture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
int counter = 0;

private void _CalculateValue()
{
    double b = 0.1;

    a = _a * b;

    counter++;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to move the variable declaration outside of the method.

```
class myClass
{    
    int counter = 0;
    private void _CalculateValue()
    {
         double b = 0.1;
         a = a * b;
         counter++;    
    }
}
```